# CSS :nth-child custom equation

Tags: css, css-selectors

When using CSS pseudo class, I could select every number of x elements and I don't have to target it manually....but when using 3n+1 equation the number will always start from 1, what if I want to start from 2 onwards?

for example:

```
.abc(3n+1) {background: red;}
```

would select the 1,4,7,10 and so on

but what if I want to skip the first and select the second onwards, like so, 2,4,7,10....

Is there a equation for this?

Comment: 2,4,7,10 isn't any pattern i don't think there is a solution!!! would help me even if there is one :)

Comment: If you meant '4,7,10 and so on', just write `.abc(3n+4)`, If you meant '2,5,8,11' write `.abc(3n+2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot) selector to prevent selecting the `:first-child`

```css
.abc:nth-child(3n+1):not(:first-child),
.abc:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}
```

Or you could reset the applied styles to the *first* div by overriding:

```css
.abc:first-child { /* default styles... */ }
```

**[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/uxejOte/1/edit)**.

### Just for clarification

CSS3 `nth-child()` or `nth-of-type()` selectors don't work for combination of `element.class`, they look for the `element` itself.

Considering that, you should make sure that all the `.abc` elements are **siblings**.

Or wrap all the elements by a wrapper called `.abc` then select the `element` children as follows:

```
.abc element:nth-child(3n+1):not(:first-child),
.abc element:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: pseudo-classes do not work on classes only elements. I did **not** downvote.

Comment: @Paulie_D I know, I just added this snippet as a demo.

Comment: Dear Downvoter any feedback is appreciated, if you could tell why?

Comment: @Paulie_D In my Example, there's no hierarchy in the DOM. and this works. Check the online demo.

Comment: I did...now change one of the classes from .abc to something else and the demo fails. **nth-of-class** is not possible in CSS although via JS/HQ it can be done.

Comment: @Paulie_D the expected Markup structure should be explained by the OP himself. It's just a demo as I said couple of times before.

Answer (score 1):

I dont see an equation to achieve this but this hack should work.

```
.abc:nth-child(3n+1), .abc:nth-child(2) {background: red;}

.abc:first-child {background: green} /* say the original background for the first element was green*/
```

Comment: Where did you come up with `:second` and `:first`? There aren't any such selectors in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

The option(s) you want don't fit any specific pattern so you would have to use two selectors.

Firstly, however, you cannot apply **nth** pseudo-classes to actual classes..only elements.

If you have a menu with 10 `li`...say

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="">5</a></li>
  <li><a href="">6</a></li>
  <li><a href="">7</a></li>
  <li><a href="">8</a></li>
  <li><a href="">9</a></li>
  <li><a href="">10</a></li>
</ul>
```

then you would need **two** selectors

```
li:nth-child(3n+4),
li:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

**:nth-child(3n+4)** selects every third item **starting** with the 4th.

**:nth-child(2)** slects just the second item

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/oDikB)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way what i think better is

```
.abc li:nth-child(3n+4),.abc li:nth-child(2){//supposing abc to be class of ul and has li
    // what ever goes in here..
}
```

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wizam/UwKH3/1/)

Comment: pseudo-classes do not work on classes only elements.

Comment: @Paulie_D: They do work on classes, just not often as the author would expect.